# Swift Realm filter issue

Tags: swift, filter, realm, predicate

I have a Swift Realm database that I’m attempting to find a specific record which will occupy a number of Labels in a UIViewController - no Tableview. In essence, I want to search the database for a record based on a String variable consisting of a date and time. The string format looks like this “Feb19,21-15:47” but changes with each new record added - hence why I need to use a string variable as a search parameter.

Once the record is found I want to then grab the entire record associated with the search string and parse out each field to fill the five Labels on the VC. I’ve been trying for hours to get this to work but I’m just not getting the result I need.

My questions are:

1. How do I format the search parameter to find the record using tempPhotoTitle?
2. Once the search finds the object property (tempPhotoTitle) in the database what code needs to be employed to grab all the associated properties in the same record/row so I can bind each property to its associated Label in the VC.

A couple notes: I did employ an auto updating primary key in each record named ‘id’. When using a Tableview I can access each record by using indexPath.row but since I’m not using a TV this isn’t available. The tempPhotoTitle string value is fed from another VC via a segue. Also only one record in the DB will have the search value. Here is some abbreviated code to provide the gist of my issue. The search doesn’t work (parsing issue) and as a result I can’t test the remaining code. I sure would appreciate some assistance on this. Many thanks and frustrated Roger

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

 
class Snapshot: Object {
   
    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var date: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var cTime: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var airTemp:     String = ""
    @objc dynamic var humidity:    String = ""
    @objc dynamic var photoTitle: String = ""
 
   
    
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "id"
}
 
convenience init( ….)
 
}

 
 
class RecordsVC: UIViewController {
 
    var tempPhotoTitle: String = ""
    var tempImage = UIImage()
   
    
    @IBOutlet weak var eDateHolder: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var eTimeHolder: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var eAirTempHolder: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var eHumidityHolder: UILabel!
    

var editSnapShotItems: Results<Snapshot>?



override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         queryRecords()

}}

func queryRecords() {
       
        let realm = try! Realm()
       
        let allRecords = realm.objects(editSnapShotItems.self)
       
        let recordResult = allRecords.filter("photoTitle CONTAINS[cd] %@",   tempPhotoTitle)
        let recordResults = allRecords.filter(tempPhotoTitle)
       
        for record in recordResults {

        eDateHolder.text = record.date
        eTimeHolder.text = record.cTime
        eAirTempHolder.text = record.airTemp
        eHumidityHolder.text = record.humidity
       
}}}
```

Comment: It's not clear why *I need to use a string variable as a search parameter.* but I threw out an answer that may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of your object for this answer

```
class Snapshot: Object {
    @objc dynamic var date: String = ""
}
```

if you create an object

```
let snap = Snapshot()
snap.date = "Feb19,21-15:47"
```

and then store it in Realm

```
let realm = try! Realm()
realm.write {
   realm.add(snap)
}
```

and then you want to find that later

```
let snapResults = realm.object(Snapshot.self).filter("date == %@", "Feb19,21-15:47")
for snap in snapResults {
   print(snap.date)
}
```

the console output will be

```
Feb19,21-15:47
```

But...

There are a number of issues with storing dates in that format. For example, what if you want to sort three dates Jan20,21-15:57, Jan21,21-15:57, Feb19,21-15:57. Logically they are in order but because they are strings, they will sort with Feb19 first (F is before J in the alphabet).

There are a number of solutions: Realm fully supports NSDate so you can just store them as an actual date or if you really want to use strings, store them in a sortable format

```
202102191547
```

would be Feb 19th 2021 at 15:47, making sure single digits are padded with a 0. This allows them to be ordered, filtered etc correctly

Comment: Thanks Jay - exactly what I was hoping for.  Your comment about sorting makes perfect sense and I will make the necessary adjustments. Your time is appreciated!